# Get URL of specific domain from a text if this text contains a certain date pattern

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed

I have a String `STRING` of this form:

```
[CDATA[A title for the URLs with a date 2013.12.10 in it<br /><br />

    http://www.foobar.com/foo/bar
    <br />http://bar.com/foo
    <br />http://myurl.com/foo
    <br />http://desiredURL.com/files/ddd
    <br />http://asdasd.com/onefile/g.html
    <br />http://second.com/link
    <br />]]
```

Theres a date in the first line that I need to compare to today's date and if that is `true` I want to get the URL of a specific domain from one of the succeeding lines.
I have done some parsing on the date line:

```
DATE=`date +%Y.%m.%d`
LINEDATE=`echo "$line" | grep  $DATE |   sed -nre 's/^[^0-9]*(([0-9]+\.)*[0-9]+).*/\1/p'`
```

So what I need is a regular expression that finds in between  `[CDATA` and `]]` said Datepattern and if this is todays date, gets the URL of domain `desiredURL.com`. Maybe something like this:

```
URL = `echo $STRING | sed 'Pattern'`
```

Where URL is empty if the string didnt contain todays date or did not contain a url of that domain (or both).

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
DATE=`date +%Y.%m.%d`
DESIRED="desiredURL.com"
URL=`echo ${STRING} | sed -n s"/.*\[CDATA\[\(.*${DATE}.*${DESIRED}.*\)\]\].*/\1/gp"`
echo "URL=${URL}"
```

Comment: But this neither checks if the string contains todays date, nor does it filter the URL of the desired domain.

Comment: Does the date always appear before the desired domain?

Comment: Yes, the scheme is always like that. First line contains the date and the following lines contain one URL each.

Comment: This gives a `gp: bad substitution` when I replace `DESIRED` with `domain.com`

Comment: Did you replace the ${} also?

Comment: How would you chaneg the regex if there were no `\n` newlines in the string?

Comment: I would not change the regex string as `.` represents any character to include a newline.

Answer (score 1):

In KSH/AIX (so pipe var work outside the line and sed is POSIX and not GNU sed)

```
date +"%Y[.]%m[.]%d" | read DATE
echo "desiredURL.com" | sed 's/\./[.]/g' | read -r URL

echo "${STRING}" | sed -n "/A title for the URLs with a date ${DATE}/, {
   /${URL}/ s|^[[:blank:]]*<br />||p
   }'
```

Be carrefull of RegEx char in your `A title for the URLs with a date`

Comment: Thanks. I should have mentioned the characters surrounding the date are not always what I have in my example. They can change.

Comment: you can indeed assume [CDATA[ is the trigger so a /^[[:blank:]]*\\[CDATA\\[.*${DATE}/ could be used instead